# Tools to develop an application that works in most browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, css

I am working on many browser issues. I got a doubt if is it possible to develop an application compatible with all browsers, or the vast majority, it needs to be web application.
Any suggestions on frameworks and tools?

Comment: What specific problems are you having? Is it in the display, in the backend? Stackoverflow is for specific, code-related questions. This is extremely broad.

Comment: `on many browser issues` - Welcome to the world of web development :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible for the vast majority. I recommend you check out out

- [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) - predictable layout across browsers & screen sizes
- [jquery](http://jquery.com/) - avoid browser specific javascript

Comment: These are tools I would recommend also +1

Comment: I would't suggest bootstrap because it's really just a collection of antipatterns.

Comment: Thanks it is use full for me

Answer (score 0):

Few advices on **Javascript**: Use 3rd party libraries which are masking compatibility issues. Examples:

**jQuery**: masks browser-specific event details, and fixes many other stuff

**JSON2**: fix for missing JSON definitions in certain browsers

**html5shim**: fix for html5 support in certain browsers

**raphael**: fixes SVG/VML mess with uniform API (useful if you use IE8 and lesser)

Regarding **CSS and HTML** compatibilites: it really depends on if you want to support IE prior to version 9. IE9 have most issues fixes.

Comment: Ny question is about how to make application as browser comptable for all browsers

Answer (score 0):

There are hundreds of tools to assist with this, but really the best thing to do is learn web standards: http://www.w3.org